# Python: Recursive function and storing variable

Tags: python, recursion

I have a recursive function, simulation(), that fetches some values (the values are the results of counting several actions) off the web every minute or so. Inside of the function is a nested function, raise_alarm, also recursive, that uses the values from simulation() as arguments and analyzes them. I need to be able to detect if there has been a change in value after each run.

I have refrained from using global variables (don't really know much about them) as I keep reading, they should be the last resort. So is there any way that I can store a value inside or outside the nested function, in order to be able to compare it with its updated state, once it has arrived?

Here is the simplified code:

```
    def simulation():
        #generates the values_a, _b...
       def raise_alarm(value_a, value_b,...):
           if value_a_old < value_a:    ###where do I place value_a_old?)
               #do stuff  
           else: pass          
           if value_b_alt < value_b:
               #do stuff
           else: pass            
           if value_a > value_b+2 or value_b > value_a+2:
               #do stuff
           else:
               #do other stuff
        while True:
            print' stuff '
            time.sleep(2)
            raise_alarm(value_a, value_b)
    simulation()
```

So in detail, value_a,_b… are being scraped off the web continuously. Each time value_b has grown 3 times on average, value_b also grows by 1. I need a variable inside my raise_alarm-function that is mirroring value_a, but will be set back to 0 every time value_b changes.
For this i want to store value_a in the storage-variable value_a_old, so i can compare the new incoming value_a with the value_a_old. Both, value_a and value_a_old need get updated during the course.

Hope, you know what I'm talking about, I have been staring at it all day…

Cheers, guys!

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to pass the variables you need, e.g. `value_a_old`, as a parameter to `raise_alarm()`.

Comment: `simulation` does not appear to be recursive; actually, neither does `raise_alarm`.

Comment: Where exactly is the execution flow recursing?

Comment: You can/should remove all `else: pass` lines

Comment: simulation() has a while True loop (not in my simplified code), so does raise_alarm. I need them to run continuously until I stop them manually.

Comment: @tao_oat: I tried that, but each time the function starts again, the value_a_old gets reset to my starting value (0). But I need it to keep the value it had in the run before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe pack both simulation() and raise_alarm() inside a class and use object parameters? That would provide a nice, shared scope for the values you'd like to share.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about working with classes, apart from how to create one. simulation() is just a -> simulation of a web-scraping function, not sure, if that should be in a class. I'm pretty new to all this. I will look into classes. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, how to use classes for that purpose. I guess, I will look into global variables.

Comment: I created several classes now, but I am having troubles making them interact and creating instances through my web-scraping function. Can you recommend any page/course/source where I can read more about using classes for OOP. All I can find is either too basic and stops after explaining how to make a class and instance or it is too technical for my level of experience.